# Opening an external app from a react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to open an external application from a react native application. I passed the URL and it calls the application but it shows loading screen only and doesn't show the application.
Could anyone suggest the possible reason?

I tried using react-native-app-link which seems to be outdated and not useful. Then I tried linking.openurl(WhatsApp://) but it didn't work as well

`Linking.openURL("whatsapp://app")`

The external app should open.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to open only Whatsapp through your application then
refer `https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013`

thank,

hope this helps you